# Transforming a delay-differential equation into an ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

Is it possible to transform the following system of delay-differential equations into a system of ordinary equations:

$u_E'(t) = I_0 - u_E(t) -W_E(1 -\frac{2^4}{2^4+u_I(t-\tau)^4})$

$u_I'(t) = - u_I(t) + W_I(1 - \frac{2^4}{2^4+u_E(t-\tau)^4})$

$I_0$, $W_E$ and $W_I$ are constants.

Comment: Time shifting is multiplication by phase ramp in the fourier domain, but those raised to 4th powers will be nasty over there. What are the $W$s? Constants?

Comment: Yes, the $W$s are constants.

Comment: Would be slightly easier expressions if you rewrite $\frac{k+u^4-k}{k+u^4}$ and then split to get $1 - \frac{k}{k+u^4}$